# bath tub faucet drip

Tags: leak, faucet, bathtub

After shutting off the main water supply (at the end of my driveway) and removing the faucet handle and the spout, the pipe from the spout still drips water after two hours. I was trying to replace the cartridge, but I can't get the final ring of to remove the old cartridge. I sprayed with W-4  in the hope that thing loosens, but no movement. 
I don't know what brand it is, but it is white and much bigger than the ones I see on videos.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! What's your question? Is it about the spout dripping? Or how to remove the old cartridge?

Comment: A picture (and make/model) of the hose bibb would help us help you.

Comment: Are there other fixtures or faucets in the house at a higher elevation? Then open those so the water can drain out your lower faucet. Otherwise, the pipes hold water and continue to dribble.